# To what extent do African dialects of Italian differ from their European counterparts?

Tags: romance-languages, language-contact, italian, dialects

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language#Africa), Italian is spoken to some degree in Libya, Eritrea and Federal Republic of Somalia.

Are there in Africa any *clearly different* varieties of this language which have *distinct* local traits?

Comment: Your question is contradictory. The title presumes that there are distinct African dialects of Italian then the body asks if there are distinct dialects of Italian in Africa.

Comment: None of this editing is helping--the latest makes the question title even less connected to the body of the question.

Comment: The title postulates that there are different Italian dialects in Africa while the text asks if they are clearly different (or not).

Comment: They're only different dialects if they *are* clearly different; if they're *not* clearly different then they *are not* different dialects. Also, the question title doesn't just postulate, it *presumes* that there are "African dialects of Italian"; the question body then asks, in effect, if there are African dialects of Italian.

Comment: That's just your misinterpretation of my words. E.g. Scottish, Cockney and Singapore dialects are the dialects of English, of which Scottish and Cockney are less (or not-so-clearly) different and Singapore English is more, or distinctly, different.

Comment: I think speakers of Scottish English and Cockney would consider them very different. Certainly there are numerous systematic (and clear) differences between the two: have a look at [this page](http://dialectblog.com/british-accents/) and compare the two. Re 'Singapore English', if by this you are referring to Singlish, yes that's very different, perhaps even a different language altogether.

Comment: I think the speakers are not linguists. And - no, by Singapore English I mean Singapore English, the variaty of a language influenced by Chinese, Tamil, Malay and, to a lesser extent, Dutch. What you call Singlish is just a part of it.

Comment: I don't see the point of the bickering here. Why not just change the "dialects" in the wording to "varieties"?

Comment: @hippietrail: because I have zero tolerance for bigotism and because dialect is a living branch of a language tree while varieties are  most often constructed artificially (e.g. Japanese and Singapore Englishes are not English dialects, they are varieties). Also because I want my words and my intentions be as I have thought them and as I have said  them, not as the other persons want them to be 'improved'.

Answer (score 4):

The only Italian colony with any substantial settlement was Libya which mostly occurred in the 1930s. Just before WWII over 100,000 or 1/8 of the inhabitants were Italian settlers, or [Italo-Libyans](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italo-libici), many of whom left during and after the war. A common estimate for 1962 is 35.000 Italians in Libya. They were ordered to leave after al-Gaddafi took power, though it seems there was still some 1,500 in the country by 1982.

There was simply no time for a Libyan Italian dialect to evolve.

Comment: Egypt was not an Italian colony but the Italian population was substantial and before that there was a Venetian population for a long time.